# Set audit user with Spring AuditorAware

Tags: jooq

I am currently trying to set my own user over the audit provider. However, I always get an error with the insert that these columns are missing with the select? What is wrong?

So to grab the information works:

```
public class AuditorAwareJooqProvider extends DefaultAuditProvider {

   private final AuditorAware<String> auditorProvider;

   public AuditorAwareJooqProvider( final AuditorAware<String> auditorProvider ) {
      this.auditorProvider = auditorProvider;
   }

   @Override
   public <T> Field<T> provideUser( final GeneratorContext<?, ?, T> ctx ) {
      final Field<T> f = ctx.field();
      final Class<T> t = f == null ? (Class<T>) String.class : f.getDataType().getType();

      if ( t == String.class ) {
         final String currentAuditor = auditorProvider.getCurrentAuditor().orElseThrow( () -> new IllegalArgumentException( "No Auditor is set" ) );
         return (Field<T>) DSL.val( currentAuditor );
      } else {
         return null;
      }
   }

}
```

Exception:

```
org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [declare @result table ([id] bigint); insert into [foo] ([name], [created_by], [last_modified_by], [created_at], [last_modified_at]) output inserted.[id] into @result select [name], ?, ? from (select ?, ?, ?) [t] ([name]); select [id] from @result [r];]; The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.
    at org.jooq_3.18.4.SQLSERVER.debug(Unknown Source)
    at org.jooq.impl.Tools.translate(Tools.java:3470)
    at org.jooq.impl.Tools.translate(Tools.java:3458)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultExecuteContext.sqlException(DefaultExecuteContext.java:772)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:371)
    at org.jooq.impl.TableRecordImpl.storeInsert0(TableRecordImpl.java:197)
    at org.jooq.impl.TableRecordImpl.lambda$storeInsert$0(TableRecordImpl.java:163)
    at org.jooq.impl.RecordDelegate.operate(RecordDelegate.java:144)
    at org.jooq.impl.TableRecordImpl.storeInsert(TableRecordImpl.java:162)
    at 
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.
```

Generator:

```
      <forcedType>
                   <name>BIGINT</name>
                   <auditInsertTimestamp>true</auditInsertTimestamp>
                   <includeExpression>created_at</includeExpression>
                </forcedType>
                <forcedType>
                   <name>BIGINT</name>
                   <auditUpdateTimestamp>true</auditUpdateTimestamp>
                   <auditInsertTimestamp>true</auditInsertTimestamp>
                   <includeExpression>last_modified_at</includeExpression>
                </forcedType>
                <forcedType>
                   <auditInsertUser>true</auditInsertUser>
                   <includeExpression>created_by</includeExpression>
                </forcedType>
                <forcedType>
                   <auditUpdateUser>true</auditUpdateUser>
                   <auditInsertUser>true</auditInsertUser>
                   <includeExpression>last_modified_by</includeExpression>
                </forcedType>
```

Comment: The documentation explains how to specify a `Configuration.auditProvider()`. Have you tried this?

Comment: I can try that. 
I wasn't sure if it's recommendable to use your own audit provider together with spring beans.

Comment: jOOQ has no opinion about Spring

Comment: @LukasEder edited the question and add more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `provideTimestamp` from the audit provider do not support `BIGINT`.
I add this and worked so far

```
@Override
   public <T> Field<T> provideTimestamp( final GeneratorContext<?, ?, T> ctx ) {

      final long now = Instant.now().toEpochMilli();
      final Field<T> timestampField = ctx.field();
      final Class<T> timestampClass = timestampField == null ? (Class<T>) Long.class : timestampField.getDataType().getType();

      if ( timestampClass == Long.class ) {
         return (Field<T>) DSL.val( now );
      }

      return super.provideTimestamp( ctx );
   }
```

Thanks @Lukas for support

Comment: Interesting point. I don't see any reason why the `AuditProvider` should forbid `BIGINT` timestamps. It just currently doesn't officially support it. I've created a feature request to change the contract on the Javadoc, and make sure it does work, going forward: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/15410